# When merging multiple csv files and uploading the merged file into Tableau, I discovered that there is a problem where the merges are

Tags: excel, csv, tableau-api

I merged 12 .csv files, keeping only the header from the first file. For context, the header for each original file has a first entry of 'ride_id' and a last entry of 'member_casual'. Each non-header row's last entry will either have a string of 'member' or 'casual'. The code I put in my Mac terminal to merge the files is: `cat 202110-divvy-tripdata_v02.csv <( tail +2 202111-divvy-tripdata_v02.csv) <(tail +2 202112-divvy-tripdata_v02.csv) <(tail +2 202201-divvy-tripdata_v02.csv) <(tail +2 202202-divvy-tripdata_v02.csv) <(tail +2 202203-divvy-tripdata_v02.csv) <(tail +2 202204-divvy-tripdata_v02.csv) <(tail +2 202205-divvy-tripdata_v02.csv) <(tail +2 202206-divvy-tripdata_v02.csv) <(tail +2 202207-divvy-tripdata_v02.csv) <(tail +2 202208-divvy-tripdata_v02.csv) <(tail +2 202209-divvy-publictripdata_v02.csv) > merged2.csv`

Once I put the data in tableau, I looked at how many of each string appears in the member_casual column. It returns that I have strings: 'member', 'casual', 'memberride_id', and 'casualride_id'. I have 8 'casualride_id' and 3 'memberride_id'. These directly correspond to where the merge happens. So when merging, the very last string in the 'member_casual' column gets concatenated with the first entry ('ride_id') from the header of the 2nd file.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem while merging? I am new to merging .csv files and tableau and would appreciate some help.

I'm lost at what to try. I tried to look up solutions online but didn't find any.

Comment: There are Tableau settings that allow .csv files to be "unioned" (aka merged) at import time and there are enough options to ignore the first row of each file. It is also possible to use wildcards to select which files are included in the import. This is probably far easier than manually merging the files before import.

Answer (score 1):

To further Matt's comment, it works like this.

I have these files in the same folder.

[image]

Drag `New Union` to the table pane.

Click the Wildcard (automatic) tab.

Use the `*` for a wildcard.

[image]

Expand your search as necessary. My search will pick up the chunk_results_0 and chunk_results_1 files.

You will have a new `Path` field in your dataset to distinguish between the different files that are picked up.